# Declining a full-time offer and asking for a part-time position?

Tags: communication, career-switch, health, fulltime, part-time

I have received an *full time* offer from a prestigious hospital for registered nurse position. I recently changed my long term career goals and decided to pursue medical school/doctor position. However, the only reason why I applied to a full time position is because it is hard to find part time nursing job as a new graduate and I need the money/return on my nursing education. How can I politely decline the full time offer and ask for a part time position ? Please note that from experience I know nurses tend to look down on people who leave nursing for medicine so I don't want to mention my plans to attempt medical school. Thanks for any advice !

Comment: What @JoeStrazzere has said.  If they had wanted a part time person, they would have advertised for it.  Since you already know it's difficult to get part time work in your field, then it's highly unlikely they will offer that to you after you have accepted a full time position.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I specifically did not apply for a full time position. During the interview I was told it will be a full time position. However, I didn't ask the manager at that time for part time position. Partly because I didn't think I will get the position and partly since I believed it will ruin my chances all together. I now realize I should have voiced this matter during the interview.

Comment: @JennaMaiz If you are prepared to lose the job as full time, or at least would not take the full time position, then there is no harm in asking now if they would consider part time.  If they say no, then you are at least you both walk away and they go to the next preferred candidate.

Comment: consider changing your username to not-your-name!

Comment: @bharal bharal is not your real name?

Comment: In the question you specifically state applied to a full time position but in a comment you you state you did not apply to a full time position.  If you don't want to offend nurses then don't  use the term "leave nursing for medicine".   If you are not going to tell them about medical school then what are you going to say if they ask why?

Comment: Assuming you work as a nurse but want to study (further) in medicine, why would anyone consider that "leaving" nursing? You *are* a nurse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Career**

- It's definitely important to think about your longterm career before anything else. Please don't worry about what others will think of you if you decide to go back to college.

**Finance**

- Now, I'm not exactly sure why you can't take the full-time job, but if you haven't gotten into medical school then I would definitely suggest taking the job full time while you apply. There's a lengthy application process which might take up to a year to complete if not more if you need to take the MCAT.
- It's also a known fact that medical school has quite a hefty price tag on it. Another reason to stay for the full time position would be to save up for that. Unless your contract says otherwise, you are allowed to leave your job whenever you need to.

**Asking for part time**

- Remember that the worst they can say is no. If they've already offered you a position, they're not going to take it away from you if you're asking for part time. Say that you life circumstances have changed and you need to switch to part time. Ask them if that's an availability.. I would recommend meeting with them in person before accepting the position.

Congratulations and good luck in your future endeavors!